# Use a C++/CLI DLL using afxwinforms.h as Reference of another C++/CLI DLL also using afxwinforms.h

Tags: dll, mfc, c++-cli

In Visual C++ 2010 i added a reference from a C++/CLI DLL (**ControlWrapper.dll**) to another C++/CLI DLL (**CliLibrary.dll**).

Both are including afxwinforms.h in the stdafx.h.

When i try to compile i get these errors:

```
error C2011: 'Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWin32Window' : 'class' type redefinition
error C2011: 'Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsEventsHelper' : 'class' type redefinition
```

If i turn of the Option *Reference Assembly Output* and add `#using "CliLibrary.dll"` to the using .cpp File i get the following warnings:

```
1>ControlWrapper.dll : warning C4944: 'CWin32Window' : cannot import symbol from 'c:\dev\trunk\CliLibrary.dll': as 'Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWin32Window' already exists in the current scope
1>     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwinforms.h(83) : see declaration of 'Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWin32Window'
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft.VisualC.MFC.CWin32Window' from assembly 'CliLibrary, Version=1.0.4843.17337, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
1>ControlWrapper.dll : warning C4944: 'CWinFormsEventsHelper' : cannot import symbol from 'c:\dev\sfirm\trunk\sfclrlib\debug\sfclrlib.dll': as 'Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsEventsHelper' already exists in the current scope
1>          C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\afxwinforms.h(122) : see declaration of 'Microsoft::VisualC::MFC::CWinFormsEventsHelper'
1>          This diagnostic occurred while importing type 'Microsoft.VisualC.MFC.CWinFormsEventsHelper' from assembly 'CliLibrary, Version=1.0.4843.17337, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

How could i solve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a painful problem.  It certainly explains why you are the first programmer I ever encountered that actually uses this.  The problem is caused by this declaration in afxwinforms.h:

```
public ref class CWin32Window : public System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window
// etc..
```

The *public* keyword is the killer, that adds the class to the manifest of your assembly.  So when you reference it in another project that also includes the header then there are two definitions of the class.  The mix of both native and managed classes in that header prevents a clean solution.

I think you already found the best solution, using the #include, with #pragma comment(disable:4944) to shutup the compiler.  Including the header inside a namespace might be another viable hack, it renames the namespace of CWin32Window, but I'd expect trouble when linking mfcm90.lib.  Restructuring your solution and keeping all winforms code inside one project is the only thing I can recommend.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the types in afxwinforms.h?

If not (like in my case), the solution is to comment the include and add this two lines:

```
#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>
#using <System.Drawing.dll>
```

or add a reference to that two assemblies in your Project.